# Brownian motion increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We know that if $W_t$ is a Brownian motion, $W_{t+t_0}-W_{t_0}$ is one too.

Does the "converse" holds : I have a Brownian motion $W_t$  and I seek another Brownian motion, $W^*$ such that $W_t=W^*_{t+t_0}-W^*_{t_0}$ does such Brownian motion exists ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want their distributions to be equal, and sure, you can have many BMs living together. If they are plainly equal, you're not really constructing anything.

To be precise, Levys characterization tells us that any continuous (local) martingale with quadratic variation $ <W,W> _t = t$, starting at zero, is a Brownian motion.

For both the sentence above and your increments $W_{t+t_0}^* - W_t^*$ you will have to do this:

It is enough to show that the increments are independent of the past (alternatively showing $ W_{s+t_0}-W_s $ independent of filtration $ F_s$, to be precise), and that the increment has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t_0$. Then it is a 1D Brownian motion.

Comment: I'm not sure they want the distributions to be equal. Rather, I assume they're asking something along the lines of, "Can my given Brownian Motion be embedded within a larger Brownian motion?"  (if that makes any sense). I think viewing $W_t$ as being equal to $W^\ast_{t+t_0}$ would be seen as embedding $W_t$ within a larger Brownian motion.